# Java Web in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I installed Netbeans 8.1 (In Ubuntu) from the Oracle website here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

However, after installing it and trying to open a New Project, this is the options I have, and I cannot see the Java Web option.

[image]

However, from what I've seen in tutorials it should look like this:

[image]

Why can I not see the Java Web Option?

Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!1

Comment: If you want to develop web applications you will need NetBeans for EE (Enterprise Edition). You can download it from https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html (make sure you select proper platform) so try to uninstall the one you downloaded and install new one.

Comment: Downlod 208mb file from https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: Thanks. That solved my issue

Comment: thanks, guys. that helped me so much

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto https://netbeans.org/downloads/
2. Download "Java SE" bundle
3. Run .sh (script if you are also on linux)